# Can I download and cross-compile the FTP package for my embedded board

Tags: ftp, mips, cross-compiling, openwrt

Can I download and cross-compile the FTP package for my embedded board. The board is running the openwrt linux distro on mips 34k.

My Board doesn't seem to have any utility by which I can transfer the files from my host PC. I have shown the `busybox` output below as suggested by @sawdust:

Please point out the steps briefly if the above is possible.

`busybox` output:

`Currently defined functions:
        [, [[, arping, ash, awk, basename, brctl, bunzip2, bzcat, cat, chgrp, chmod, chown, chroot, clear, cmp, cp, crond, crontab, cut, date, dd,
        df, diff, dirname, dmesg, du, echo, egrep, env, expr, false, fgrep, find, free, fsync, grep, gunzip, gzip, halt, head, hexdump, hostid,
        hwclock, id, ifconfig, init, insmod, kill, killall, killall5, klogd, less, ln, lock, logger, logread, ls, lsmod, md5sum, mkdir, mkfifo,
        mknod, mktemp, mount, mv, nc, netmsg, netstat, nice, nslookup, ntpd, passwd, pgrep, pidof, ping, ping6, pivot_root, poweroff, printf, ps,
        pwd, readlink, reboot, reset, resize, rm, rmdir, rmmod, route, sed, seq, sh, sleep, sort, start-stop-daemon, strings, switch_root, sync,
        sysctl, syslogd, tail, tar, tee, telnet, telnetd, test, tftp, time, top, touch, tr, traceroute, true, udhcpc, umount, uname, uniq, uptime,
        uudecode, uuencode, vconfig, vi, watchdog, wc, wget, which, xargs, yes, zcat`

Comment: Transferring and installing a binary file to a SBC depends on what hardware you have available and what software is already installed.  If U-Boot is already installed (or Linux), then you have to look at the configuration options and the available HW.  Is there a USB host port?  Is there an Ethernet port?  Is there a SD card slot?  Are you using a RS-232 connection to a host PC? *"My Board doesn't have any utility by which I can transfer the files from my host PC"* -- You probably don't know what commands to look for or use.  What does `busybox` output when you type that at the shell prompt?

Comment: In above comments I have copied the relevant info from command `busybox`. I didn't know about the busybox, and I don't have a USB interface, I want to transfer files using ethernet Interface. I tried using serial Interface with tftp but it used to time out before the file will transfer fully. In the nutshell I want to transfer files through ethernet interface.

Comment: (1) You should edit your post with the new information, instead of making several comments.  (2) *"I want to transfer files through ethernet interface"* -- The installed Busybox has the **tftp** command, so use that.  *"I tried using serial Interface with tftp"* -- **tftp** uses Ethernet, so you need to explain how you managed to set this up!  You need to setup a ***tftp server*** on the host PC, and use Ethernet, not the serial port.

Comment: yeah in (2) i wrote serial by mistake, was using ethernet only, but as I said it timed out. And I will take care about (1) next time.

Comment: *"but as I said it timed out"* -- Then you need to need to accurately explain what you have done.  Trying to replace **tftp** with FTP is not worth the effort. You will probably run into the exact same issues as you already have.

Comment: Well the problem was not with tftp. Its working fine now. I can successfully put files to my development board from host pc. The problem was with Lan it seems, it was being flooded with UDP packets when I was trying to do the tftp transfer.

Comment: Secondly I was encountering an access violation error while "getting" files from the board. Creating an empty file with full permissions in my tftp folder on server solved the issue. The following link helped me out: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netkit-tftp/+bug/901273

Comment: *"Secondly I was encountering an access violation error while "getting" files from the board"* -- That can be configured with an option when starting the server.  But your original question only mentioned *"transfer the files from my host PC"*.

Comment: Let me know the _configuration_ for correcting the "access violation error" in the **right manner**? Mine is just a fix it seems.

Comment: **--create**   See the [Linux man page for tftpd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tftpd) for details on all options.